# Desmos - plot x vs t instead of y vs x

Tags: education, desmos

My physics students get very confused when they go from math class, where x is always (! stop that!) the horizontal axis, to physics where we put all kinds of things on the horizontal axis, including at the beginning, t (time).

They do love making graphs with Desmos. I've looked around for how to rename the variables in the Desmos graphing calculator to no avail.

Desired output:
using the form:
$x=v_0t+\frac{1}{2}at^2$
make a plot in Desmos graphing calculator with $t$ on the horizontal axis.

Comment: https://help.desmos.com/hc/en-us/articles/4405296853517-Graph-Settings

Comment: You can change the horizontal axis to be called "t", but I think the vertical axis is always $y$ in the equations ...

Comment: Thanks. We can label the axes, but the kids are still using the "wrong" equations, that is they aren't using the names for quantities that they are discussing in class. Shouldn't matter. But it totally does matter when students are struggling to grock the concept of a formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a frequent user of Desmos, this also annoys me!
While I haven't found a way to change the labels associated to the axes by default, one way you may want to use is the parametric plotting function.
For the parametric equation $x=x(t)$, $y=y(t)$, simply write $(x(t),y(t))$ in a new equation in Desmos. You'll then have the option to specify the allowed values of t below.
In your case, you could use $x(t)=t$ and $$y(t)=v_{0}t+\frac{1}{2}at^{2},$$ so plotting would look like:
$$(t,v_{0}t+\frac{1}{2}at^{2})$$
with the time domain specified below (and values for $v_{0}$ and $a$ given, of course).

Here is an example:
[image]